# CSS Item in center of page pushed up when virtual keyboard is visible

Tags: css

I have the following style for a div which is positioned in the center of the page

```
<div class="myStyle">Hi All...</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
<style>
.myStyle {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

when the virtual keyboard though opens up, the div is being pushed up. I don't understand why though. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

This is because your viewport (or the element's closest `relative` positioned parent) is shrinking vertically. If you don't want it to move, you'll have to make sure the closest parent with a `relative` position has a fixed height.

Here's an example, the second div will move based on the height of the window (open the snippet Full Screen with Dev Tools opened)

```css
.row {
  width: 100vw;
}
.col {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  background: #eee;
}

.col > div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  width: 100%;
  background: #0095ee;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col" style="height: 200px;"><div>My Y center is always 100px;</div></div>
  <div class="col" style="height: 100vh;"><div>My Y xenter varies with Devtools/etc.</div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It will adjust to top 50% from viewport. Try to fix some height to that div and give css like below. Odd effect will be reduced. For eg if height of the popup is 400px and width is 600px(Width you can give in percentage as well)

```
 .div {
    width:600px;
    height:400px;
    position:fixed;
    margin : auto;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
 }
```

But if you do not want to push div at all. Then you have to mention top in pixels. To make it work in all devices, you might have to use javascript for that. Like in javascript get the height of viewport, calculate the top you want specify based on viewport height. Apply calculated top in pixels.

For eg if top you want to specify as 50%. Then pseudo javascript code is below.

```
 var divHeight = document.height;
 var desiredTop = viewportHeight/2;
 div.style.top = desiredTop;
```

But disadvantage of giving fixed top is there will be chance that div gets hidden behind the keyboard.

Comment: I set it as you suggested but it keeps being pushed up

Comment: Yea it pushes up but odd effect will be reduced. But if you dont want to push at all then you have to mention top in pixels. You can use javascript for calculating height of the viewport, calculate the top how much you want to give. Apply top in pixels. But the disadvantage of this would be like the div might get hidden behind keyboard.

Comment: Edited my answer with above comment so it might help others.